# S2S Translation runs on Windows but does not work on linux

Tags: python-3.x, azure, ubuntu, azure-cognitive-services, speech-to-text

I am using Microsoft speech to speech translation model. I have used in windows. It works fine. When I ran it on linux it gives me multiple errors. Most of which were due to dependencies that I installed on my linux. However, I am still facing problems.

****init**.py:**

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speech_sdk
from playsound import playsound

def main():    
    try:        
        global speech_config        
        global translation_config
        # Get Configuration Settings        
        load_dotenv()        
        cog_key = os.getenv('COG_SERVICE_KEY')        
        cog_region = os.getenv('COG_SERVICE_REGION')
        
        # Configure translation        
        translation_config = speech_sdk.translation.SpeechTranslationConfig(cog_key, cog_region)        
        translation_config.speech_recognition_language = 'en-US'        
        translation_config.add_target_language('fr')        
        translation_config.add_target_language('es')        
        translation_config.add_target_language('ko')
        translation_config.add_target_language('de')        
        print('Ready to translate from',translation_config.speech_recognition_language)
        # Configure speech        
        speech_config = speech_sdk.SpeechConfig(cog_key, cog_region)        
        # Get user input
        targetLanguage = ''        
        while targetLanguage != 'quit':            
            targetLanguage = input('\nEnter a target language\n de = German\n fr = French\n es = Spanish\n ko = Korean\n Enter anything else to stop\n').lower()            
            if targetLanguage in translation_config.target_languages:                
                Translate(targetLanguage)            
            else:                
                targetLanguage = 'quit'                    
    except Exception as ex:        
        print(ex)
        
def Translate(targetLanguage):    
    translation = ''
    # Translate speech
    audioFile = 'harvard.wav' 
    playsound(audioFile)
    audio_config = speech_sdk.AudioConfig(filename=audioFile)
    translator = speech_sdk.translation.TranslationRecognizer(translation_config, audio_config = audio_config)
    print("Getting speech from file...")
    result = translator.recognize_once_async().get()
    print('Translating "{}"'.format(f"+++++++++++++{result.text}"))
    translation = result.translations[targetLanguage]
    print( f"{translation}")
    with open('just_a_dummy.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.write(translation)
    # with open('just_a_dummy.txt' 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    #    print(f"**********************************************************{ file.read()}")
    # Synthesize translation    
    voices = {
        "fr": {"male": "fr-FR-DeniseNeural", "female": "fr-FR-HenriNeural"},            
        "es": {"male": "es-ES-PedroNeural", "female": "es-ES-ElviraNeural"},            
        "ko": {"male": "ko-KR-InJoonNeural", "female": "ko-KR-SunHiNeural"},
        "de": {"male": "de-DE-ConradNeural", "female": "de-DE-KatjaNeural"},
        "ms": {"male": "ms-MY-OsmanNeural", "female": "ms-MY-YasminNeural"},
        "wuu": {"male": "wuu-CN-YunzheNeural", "female": "wuu-CN-XiaotongNeural"}
    }
    
    # Prompt the user to choose the voice gender
    while True:
        voice_gender = input(f"Choose voice gender for {targetLanguage} (male/female): ").strip().lower()
        if voice_gender in ("male", "female"):
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid input. Please enter 'male' or 'female'.")
    
    selected_voice = voices[targetLanguage][voice_gender]
    speech_config.speech_synthesis_voice_name = selected_voice    
    speech_synthesizer = speech_sdk.SpeechSynthesizer(speech_config)    
    speak = speech_synthesizer.speak_text_async(translation).get()
    if speak.reason != speech_sdk.ResultReason.SynthesizingAudioCompleted:        
        print(speak.reason)
    else:
        output_audio_file = f"output_{targetLanguage}_{voice_gender}.wav"
        with open(output_audio_file, "wb") as file:
            file.write(speak.audio_data)
        print(f"Saved synthesized audio to {output_audio_file}")
        
if __name__ == "__main__":    
    main()
```

Error:cannot import name '_gi' from partially initialized module 'gi' (most likely due to a circular import) (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/**init**.py)

Note: I am using python 3.11.5

Thanks in anticipation!

Comment: please provide the code that which you tried.

Comment: The code is too long. Can't be pasted here. Is there any alternate where we can discuss the code?

Comment: @SureshChikkam I am using the below mentioned libraries.

from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speech_sdk
from playsound import playsound

Comment: Try to Update them to the latest versions  **`pip install --upgrade dotenv azure-cognitiveservices-speech playsound`**.

Comment: Please see the code

Comment: I have tried installing these dependencies but the code still does not work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255253/discussion-between-suresh-chikkam-and-babar).

Answer (score 0):

> WARNING: Skipping gi as it is not installed.

The warning `Skipping gi as it is not installed` indicates that the gi module is missing from your Python environment.

- Install the 'python3-gi' package, **`sudo apt-get install python3-gi`**  which provides the gi module. Depending on your Linux distribution.

Instead of using Microsoft's Azure Cognitive Services for speech recognition, you can use a library like SpeechRecognition, which is cross-platform and does not rely on gi.

- To translate the text that has been recognized, use the Microsoft Translator API by sending HTTP requests to the Translator API using `requests` package.

```py
import os
import requests
import speech_recognition as sr
from gtts import gTTS
import subprocess

def recognize_speech(audio_file):
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.AudioFile(audio_file) as source:
        audio = r.record(source)
    try:
        recognized_text = r.recognize_google(audio, language="en-US")
        return recognized_text
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("Google Speech Recognition could not understand the audio.")
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print(f"Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {e}")
    return None

def translate_text(text, target_language):
    subscription_key = "YOUR_MICROSOFT_TRANSLATOR_KEY"
    endpoint = f'https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/translate'
    params = {
        'api-version': '3.0',
        'to': target_language
    }
    headers = {
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscription_key,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    body = [{'text': text}]
    response = requests.post(endpoint, params=params, headers=headers, json=body)
    result = response.json()
    translated_text = result[0]['translations'][0]['text']
    return translated_text

def text_to_speech(text, language):
    tts = gTTS(text=text, lang=language)
    tts.save('output.mp3')
    subprocess.run(['mpg321', 'output.mp3'])  # Play the audio using mpg321 or another audio player

def main():
    audio_file = 'sample.wav'  # Replace with the path to your audio file
    recognized_text = recognize_speech(audio_file)
    
    if recognized_text:
        print(f"Recognized Text: {recognized_text}")
        
        target_language = 'fr'  # Change to your desired target language code
        translated_text = translate_text(recognized_text, target_language)
        
        print(f"Translation ({target_language}): {translated_text}")
        text_to_speech(translated_text, target_language)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image]

- I am able to achieve speech-to-speech translation on Linux without relying on the gi module or the azure-cognitiveservices-speech library.